# Document Visualization in android?

Tags: android, document, visualization

Is there any document visualization toolkit available for android?

Comment: what do you mean with document visualization? I would guess displaying word or pdf documents?

Comment: something like this http://prefuse.org/

Comment: Prefuse is extremely powerful and has lots of visualizations.  Which visualization would you want to use specifically.

Comment: My question is "is there something like prefuse on android"?

Comment: If an answer was to your satisfaction it would be appreciated if you marked the appropriate answer as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a prefuse equivalent for Android.  However, there are javascript equivalents.  You could use the Android webview and one of the below libraries:

- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) - This is from the creator of Prefuse
- [Javascript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/)
- [ProcessingJS](http://processingjs.org/)

Additionally, Prefuse is open source and contains links to scientific papers so it may not be too bad to port a specific visualization to Android.

**Update:**

Another option from the creators of Protovis is [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/).  One problem that both D3 and Protovis have for Android is that they depend on SVG which for some reason is not supported in the stock browser for Android 2.x and below.  Supposedly SVG support was added in Android 3.x and above though I haven't tested in the newer versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

There are many pdf viewers on the market, just search for PDF or whatever document type you're trying to open.